# Is there a way to make the bottom of Unity scroll view blurry towards the edge?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

[image]

I want to implement it like a picture using the scroll view of UGUI, but I'm looking for a way.

Since the items in the contents are scrolling, I think I need to approach them down through the mask and make them more transparent, but I'm not sure if this is the right approach.

Does anyone know how?

I've looked up some shaders but I couldn't find what I wanted because it wasn't clear from the keywords.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with an image with an alpha gradient that looks the way you want. just make sure the image has "Raycast Target" turned off so it doesn't block scrolling.